# Understanding a C Preprocessor Macro's output

Tags: c, macros

The following is a snippet of my C program:

```
 a = 5; b = 7;
 printf("\ncubef(--a) = %d", cubef(--a));
 a = 5; b = 7;
 printf("\ncubem(--a) = %d", cubem(--a));
```

Where cubef and cubem are defined as follows:

```
#define cubem(a) a*a*a
int cubef(int a) {  return a * a * a; }
```

When executed, I get the following output:

```
cubef(--a) = 64
cubem(--a) = 18
```

I understand that cubem "expands" to `--a*--a*--a` which should result in `4*3*2` which equals 24, but for some reason I am getting 18. Can someone help me understand how I am getting that output?

Here is a link to the full program, if required: https://pastebin.com/7hGYJkTi

Comment: No. What you are invoking is undefined behavior. Sequence point here is not defined.

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: Gotcha, so to help me understand a bit better behavior with multiple callings of a single variable in a macro can't be predicted?

Comment: @rclever2 that's correct. If you use macro, then using `a++` or similar is very risky and should be avoided.